# SQL/PHP - read part of value

Tags: php, mysql

I've text date in value like this "1986-04-24 18:25:14"

i don't need show the time , how can i read date only ? " the first word of value "

code :

```
<?php
$id = ((int)$_POST["id"]);
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','dbuser','pass');
mysql_query("set names utf8");
mysql_query("set charset utf8");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');  
mysql_select_db('dbname',$con);
$query="SELECT * FROM `haevm_userxtd_profiles` WHERE user_id = '$id' AND `key` = 'BASIC_BIRTHDAY' ORDER BY `haevm_userxtd_profiles`.`user_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30";
$select=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
echo $row['value'];
} 
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

note : i've tried to use SUBSTRING , but i coldn't select , something like this :

```
SELECT value, SUBSTRING(value,0,1) FROM `haevm_userxtd_profiles` WHERE user_id = '$id' AND `key` = 'BASIC_BIRTHDAY' ORDER BY `haevm_userxtd_profiles`.`user_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Thank you

Comment: either `date(column)` in mysql or `date()` function in PHP

Comment: A PHP solution `date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['value']))` should give you only date.  Or you can do `select date(ColumnName) from tablename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
SELECT value, DATE(value) FROM `haevm_userxtd_profiles` WHERE user_id = '$id' AND `key` = 'BASIC_BIRTHDAY' ORDER BY `haevm_userxtd_profiles`.`user_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: iknow bro :D  it's my poblem :)) " You can accept an answer in 4 minutes "